# How to Manipulate DOM of Applet's Web Page?

Tags: java, dom, applet

Is there any way to manipulate, from an Applet, the DOM of a HTML page that hosts that applet? When a say manipulate, i want, for example, to create new elements in the HTML's page

Comment: [Can a java applet manipulate the HTML page containing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1176198/309483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial might help you: [Manipulating DOM of Applet's Web Page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/manipulatingDOMFromApplet.html)