# Java applet DOM manipulation example?

Tags: java, javascript, dom, applet, liveconnect

I am looking to write my first Java applet (with a difference). I want to write an applet that manipulates the DOM of the page in which the applet is placed. A suitable example would show how:

1. an element can be retrieved from the DOM (by name, id or some other CSS property)
2. Insertion/deletion of an element in to the DOM (before/after) a given DOM element
3. the innerHTML of a DOM element can be changed
4. Call a javascript function and pass data from the Java applet, to the javascript function

I have searched the internet - but so far, have not come accross any such example. Is anyone aware of such an example?. If yes, please post a link, or a snippet that shows how to achieve the functionality listed above, if possible.

Comment: [Can a java applet manipulate the HTML page containing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1176198/309483)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.java2s.com is alsways a good starting point to look for examples.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/UsingJavaScriptinanApplet.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you just solve 4 and use JavaScript to do you DOM manipulation. See [JSObject](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html)