# How to manipulate DOM of Java applet's web page

Tags: java, dom, applet

I'd like to modify the value of a hidden `<input>` tag in my applet. But I don't know how to manipulate DOM elements.

I've found the article "Manipulating DOM of Applet's Web Page" in official Java SE tutorial. But when I try the following code :
`Class c = Class.forName("com.sun.java.browser.plugin2.DOM");`
I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

**Is the Java Common DOM API is installed with JDK ? It only supports special browsers ? Or we should use an other API ?**

I'm using JDK 7, browser Google Chrome and Eclipse for programming.

Best regards

Comment: [Can a java applet manipulate the HTML page containing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1176198/309483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off abstracting the DOM manipulation out to JS, since there are JS APIs that take cross-browser differences into account.  Then have the applet call the generic JS methods.

Comment: You mean create a javascript function using a cross-browser framework to manipulate DOM, like jQuery. And my Applet only needs to call the javascript function ?